# Can I have two separate projects, 1 WebForms and 1 ASP.NET MVC, to both point to the same domain?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

Is it possible to setup two separate projects, 1 WebForms and 1 ASP.NET MVC, to both point to the same domain? i.e. both point to different pages within www.somesite.com.

Here's some background on the application and why I'm asking. This is a brownfield application that is currently 2.0 WebForms and is full of WebFormy 'goodness' (i.e. ObjectDataSources, FormView controls, UpdatePanels, etc...) There are lost of other 'fun' things in the code base like 600+ Stored Procedures and 200+ line methods in the business layer code that get data from the DB via stored proc, do some processing on the data, build an HTML string using string concatenation and then return that string to the UI layer. What we are planning on doing is developing new features in MVC and slowly converting the existing features over to MVC one at a time. As part of this transition, we will also be re-writing the layers below the UI to clean up the mess there and to do things like replace the stored procedures with NHibernate and introduce an IOC container.

I know that you can run WebForms and MVC side-by-side in the same project, however, because we will be making wholesale changes to the way we do many things throughout our entire development stack, I'd like the new stuff to be a completely separate project within the solution. This should help serve as very visual reminder that this is a different way of doing things than before and make it easier to remove the old code as it is no longer needed. What I don't know is, is this even possible? Can two separate project point to the same domain?

Here's an quick example of what I'm thinking:

www.somesite.com/orders.aspx?id=123 (Orders page from existing WebForms project)
www.somesite.com/customer/987 (Customer page from new MVC project)

Answer (score 0):

I've been updating a brownfield project too. We put the views folder in the existing Web project and stuck all the other MVC related stuff (global.asax.cs, controllers, VMs, etc) in a separate class library.

Comment: I've considered that approach and it will probably be my fall back plan if I can't figure out how to get it working as a completely separate project.